# Exclude unwanted variable based on length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm doing data mining of mobile games and their current rank. Some games are not ranked, and therefore the page content is empty. But they could become ranked one day, as I am to run the script once a day, so I don't wish to exclude them completely, just skip them.

The error seems to happen af the 8th URL, which contents is literally only:

```
[]
```

I added the error in here as well after my code.

As far as I can understand the error happens because there's not content to split in the dataframe. How could I proceed from here?

So far I played around with this for loop in different variations:

```
for s in df:
    if s == []:
        continue
    else: 
        pass
```

I'm just not sure if this is the correct approach anymore.

**My goal:** I wish to skip every URL whose content is "[ ]".

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import time

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

#this function gets me all the content of a certain URL 
def get_games(url):
    url_get = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content, 'lxml')
    pros = {}
    for idx, link in enumerate(soup.find()):
        pros["{}".format(idx)] = link.get_text()
    pros_list = list(pros.items())
    p = "".join(str(x) for x in pros_list)
    pp = re.findall('\{(.*?)\}', p)      #splits the list
    data = {url: pp}
    return data

#this function cleans the data variable 
def cleaner(to_get_cleaned):
    df = pd.DataFrame(get_games(url))
    date = pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    df[date],df["category"],df["chart_type"],df["country"],df["previous_rank"] = df[url].str.split("," ,0).str #error seems to happen here
    df.drop([url],axis=1,inplace=True)       #removes first col, which includes all data in csv format
    df = df.replace(to_replace=r"^.*?:", value = "", regex=True)    #removes everything before ":"
    df = df.replace(to_replace=r"\"", value = "", regex=True)       # removes all " 
    df = df.set_index('country').reset_index()      #moves country to first col

    western = df.loc[df['country'].isin(['US', 'FR', "JP", "DE", "GB"])]    
    western = western.loc[western["category"].isin(["game"])]
    western = western.loc[western["chart_type"].isin(["topgrossing"])]
    western = western.drop(["category", "chart_type", "previous_rank"], axis=1)
    western = western.T    #transposes dataframe   
    return western.to_string(header=None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = {
        "Empire: Four Kingdoms":    "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=air.com.goodgamestudios.empirefourkingdoms&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Big Farm Mobile Harvest":  "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.goodgamestudios.bigfarmmobileharvest&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Age of Lords":             "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.eRepublikLabs.AgeOfLords&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Battle Pirates HQ":        "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.kixeye.BPCompanion&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Call of War":              "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.bytro.callofwar1942&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Empire: Age of Knights":   "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.goodgamestudios.ageofknights&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Empire: Millennium Wars":  "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.goodgamestudios.millennium&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "eRepublik":                "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.erpkmobile&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Game of Emperors":         "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.io.gameofemperors&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Game of Trenches":         "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.ww1&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Imperia Online":           "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=org.imperiaonline.android.v6&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Imperial Hero":            "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=org.imperialhero.android&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Mars Tomorrow":            "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=de.gamefab.mars&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "One Epic Knight":          "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.simutronics.oneepicknight&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Seasons of War":           "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=org.imperiaonline.android.seasons&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "SIEGE: TITAN WARS":        "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.gamealliance.siege&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "SIEGE: World War II":      "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.simutronics.b17&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Skytopia - City Tycoon":   "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.goodgamestudios.skytopia&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Supremacy 1914":           "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.bytro.supremacy1914&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Tactical Heroes 2: Platoons": "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.vietnamwar&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "Twin Shooter - Invaders":  "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.twinshooter&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "VEGA Conflict":            "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.kixeye.vegaconflict&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "War and Peace":            "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.warandpeace&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "War Commander: Rogue Assault": "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.kixeye.wcm&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z",
        "World at War: WW2 Strategy MMO":   "https://sensortower.com/api/android/rankings/for_app_and_date?app_id=com.erepubliklabs.worldatwar&date=2019-08-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z"
    }

    for category, url in url.items():
        total_items = cleaner(url)
        print("{}".format(category, url) + ":\n{}".format(total_items) + "\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        #total_items.to_excel(excel_writer="ranking.xlsx", index=False)
```

Here's the error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-f82b46453409>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/M/Desktop/games_scraper.py', wdir='/Users/M/Desktop')

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/M/Desktop/games_scraper.py", line 69, in <module>
    total_items = cleaner(url)

  File "/Users/M/Desktop/games_scraper.py", line 26, in cleaner
    df[date],df["category"],df["chart_type"],df["country"],df["previous_rank"] = df[url].str.split("," ,0).str #error seems to happen here

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5063, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 171, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1796, in __init__
    self._validate(data)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 1818, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Comment: The error suggests that at least one of the values of df[url] are is not a string so the .str accessor function throws and exception here.

Comment: Yeah, and that would be the 8th URL. How to skip this one, that is the question?

Comment: Your function definition "def cleaner(to_get_cleaned)" contains the label to_get_cleaned but this isn't used in the function body at all?

Comment: The function is supposed to take a URL as a parameter, as it does at the very bottom, and then clean the contents of that URL. The script works as it should, do you think that could be what's causing the issue?

Comment: I think your script has a variety of problems that make it difficult to see what's going wrong.  You have a global dictionary called url.  You then loop over the items of this but you're using the same name url here.  You pass this specific url to your function, cleaner, but that function isn't doing anything with that url because the name "to_be_cleaned" isn't used within the function.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Ymareth. I appreciate your taking your time to help me. But the script does exactly what I want it to do. My only issue is I need a mechanism to exclude URLs with content less than 2 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future use and anyone else having the same issue here's how I fixed it:

```
if df.empty:
    pass
else:
   print("I'm running")
```

Explanation:
"if df.empty" refers to a pandas function to check whether the dataframe is empty. And if it is I say "pass" - to continue the script, and if it ain't empty I say print "I'm running" just to check what happens.

To my own surprise it worked :)